# Google DialogFlow --> Number-Sequence entity only matches SPECIFIC length of characters

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I have an entity with type:  `@sys.number-sequence`, which matches a code 4 numbers long, for example: (Spoken) "1 2 3 4" or "1234".

In the Intent, if the user speaks a code that's 1, 2, 3, 5 or 6 characters in length and not just 4-long, this pattern does NOT match.  So in the "User Says:" section, I had to add all of the below: 
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
(And map each one to my number-sequence entity)

... to handle all permutations of 1 through 6 long number sequences.

It's obviously a very hacky and ugly solution.

Is there a way I can define a number sequence type that will match any length of number sequence so that I can use it in phrase structures in a more flexible way?

In other words:   I want to just define the placeholder match ONCE, and not have to redefine it for every length variation...

I don't see anything pertaining to "number sequence length" in the documentation of Dialog Flow types:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in entities like `@sys.number-sequence` will help you in finding numbers in sequence only. In api.ai, you can not specify the length of a number that you want either 4-digit or 6-digit. In addition, training agent for all permutations of any digit number is not a generalized solution.

What you can do is write a webhook, fetch this parameter `@sys.number-sequence` in your code & put a verification over there. If it is not of the number of digits you want, you can send a reply saying `Please enter 6 digit number` or say `you have entered a correct code`.

Comment: The reason I'm using "1" is it's actually able to allow any length of numbers.  So it accepts all of:  1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111.   If you put 1111, instead of 1 as a placeholder, then it only accepts 4 digit numbers, and rejects everything else.  (Tested this many times).  So with a 1 digit number, it's a lot more flexible, to allow any length of input.   For validation purposes, your answer is still valid - to do it in the webhook.  But I did end up with going with a placeholder of "1" - and now it matches all lengths of number-sequence.   thanks.

Comment: try number 5212, 6212,7212 with your @sys.number-sequence and you would be blown away with the way it responds. for 5212 it would give you 5.5 value :D